# Having trouble producing two seperate outputs using Random

Tags: java, random

I'm trying to create two separate outputs of 10 columns and 10 rows of numbers. The first output using numbers 4 through 7 and the second output using numbers 10 through 90 (e.g. 10, 20, 30 and so on). But calling these numbers randomly, not in a special order. Below is the Java code I have:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class LabRandom
{
private static final Random rand = new Random();
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    int number;

    int i = 1;

    while (i <= 100)
    {
        //number = rand.nextInt(4) + 4;
        System.out.printf("%-5d", rand.nextInt(4) + 4);

        if (i % 10 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println();
        }
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println();

    while (i <= 100)
    {
        //number = rand.nextInt(4) + 4;
        System.out.printf("%-5d", rand.nextInt(10 *(80) + 10));

        if (i % 10 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println();
        }
        i++;
    }
   }    
}
```

I just can't figure out what I am missing, The code only runs the first while statement and not the second while statement.

Comment: reset your i after the first while loop

Comment: Re-using variables in consecutive `while` loops leads to bugs like this. If you need X iterations, use a `for` loop. (BTW, this would be a great time to start using a debugger: setting a break-point on the second loop and inspecting the value of `i` would have made it immediately obvious what was going on!)

Comment: Also (And running a 'corrected' version will show this immediately), your second loop isn't outputting the numbers you need - you're going to need to use integer division.  That or multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't reinitialised `i`, and after the first loop, it will already equal `101`, so the second loop will not be entered.

As was mentioned in the comments on your question, a `for` loop would be a more appropriate construct here.

Also, in that second loop, the statement:

```
rand.nextInt(10 *(80) + 10)
```

Doesn't seem like it will do what you want. You probably need something like:

```
rand.nextInt(9) * 10 + 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset `i` before your second `while`.

Answer (score 0):

set the value of i before the second while loop.

```
    import java.util.Random;

    public class LabRandom
    {
    private static final Random rand = new Random();
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int number;

        int i = 1;

        while (i <= 100)
        {
            //number = rand.nextInt(4) + 4;
            System.out.printf("%-5d", rand.nextInt(4) + 4);

            if (i % 10 == 0)
            {
                System.out.println();
            }
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println();

i = 1;//modified here

        while (i <= 100)
        {
            //number = rand.nextInt(4) + 4;
            System.out.printf("%-5d", rand.nextInt(10 *(80) + 10));

            if (i % 10 == 0)
            {
                System.out.println();
            }
            i++;
        }
       }    
    }
```